# Allow XML element in any order with any number of appearance via XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have trouble to write XSD with these constraints: **Name** element is required;  **Value** element could appear 0 or multiple times; **Category** element is optional. I now have XSD like this:

```
<xs:element name="Detail" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"> <!-- 0 or more Details -->
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Name"/> <!-- Name element is required -->
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Value" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/> <!-- 0 or more occurences of Value element -->
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Category" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/> <!-- optional (0 or 1) Category element -->
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The problem is that input XML may not follow the order in the schema. And **xs:choice** and **xs:all** have appearance constraint that are not good enough for me.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem that allow XML element in any order with any number of times appearance?

Attach a sample input XML:

```
<Detail>
    <Category />
    <Name> Thanks </Name>
    <Value> 1 </Value>
    <Value> 2 </Value>
</Detail>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### XSD 1.0

Not possible.  Either impose an order, or relax occurrence constraints.

### XSD 1.1

Possible, because in XSD 1.1, children of `xs:all` may now have `@maxOccurs="unbounded"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
  vc:minVersion="1.1">
  <xs:element name="Detail"> 
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Name"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Value" 
                    minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Category" 
                    minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks. How could I check the xsd version I am currently using? "http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" shows URI is not registered.

Comment: If you attempt to validate using the shown 1.1 XSD and your processor doesn't support XSD 1.1, you'll get an error indicating that `@maxOccurs` may not be `unbounded`.

Comment: Unfortunately, my processor doesn't support 1.1. Although this doesn't solve my problem, it is still helpful that let me give up struggling with xsd and turns to other approach. Thanks a lot.